# Joomla 3 custom field get xml field

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla3.3

I am creating a custom field to create an array of input images as media type.

How can I bring back the input array with type media?

```
class JFormFieldimglist extends JFormField {

        //The field class must know its own type through the variable $type.
        protected $type = 'imglist';

        public function getLabel() {
                return "List Image";
        }

        public function getInput() {
          for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
          $images.= '<input type="text" value="'.$this->value[$i].'" name="'.$this->name.'['.$i.']" />';            
          }
             return $images;
        }
}
```

From xml i use this

```
<field name = "myimage" type = "media" directory = "stories" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.  The first issue is your extending the core JFormField class.  The second issue is the media field type is actually a modal form field.  This is a special kind of field which is used to present a more complicated interface in a modal window for the user to select.  Examples of this are when you select an Article for a Menu Type Single Article, or click the Image button located underneath the WYSIWYG editors.

My guess is you want to pull in a list of images from a specific folder for the user to select from a drop down.  In the example below notice I have completely omitted the getLabel() and getInput() methods and added getOptions().  The reason being is by extending the JFormFieldList class those methods are already built out and outside of special requirements are not needed.  You simply override the getOptions() method to provide the core class the list of option you want to be presented in the field.

```
jimport('joomla.form.helper');
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldimglist extends JFormFieldList {

    //The field class must know its own type through the variable $type.
    protected $type = 'imglist';

    public function getOptions() {
        // build out your options array
        // You should format as array, with full path as key and 
        // human readable as value
        $options = array('/images/flowers/tulip.png' => 'Tulip');
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Here are some links for expand on my post.

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type
http://docs.joomla.org/List_form_field_type
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_modal_form_field